# jQuery toggle background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I have such code to show/hide popup and divs

```
    function ToggleSendForm() {

    var effect = 'slide';
    var options = { direction: 'right', easing: 'swing' };
    var duration = 1000;
    $(".popup").toggle(effect, options, duration);
    var effectFade = 'fade';
    var durationFade = 1000;
    $(".toggler").toggle(effectFade, durationFade);
};

function UnToggleSendForm() {

    var effect = 'slide';
    var options = { direction: 'right', easing: 'swing' };
    var duration = 1000;
    $(".popup").toggle(effect, options, duration);
    var effectFade = 'fade';
    var durationFade = 1000;
    $(".toggler").toggle(effectFade, durationFade);
};

<div class="toggler" style="display: none"></div>
<div class="popup" style="background-color: #ffffff; display: none">
<div class="container" style="padding: 20px">
```

So popup slides from right side.

My problem is during the slide popup is transparent. It becomes white when expanded. But i need it white when it slides too. What i missed ?

Comment: Alexander you need to make a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: `jsfiddle.net` is your friend

Answer (score 0):

```
 { queue: false };
```

This is caused of the animation-queue in jQuery.
Set queue to false in toggle options.

```
function ToggleSendForm() {

    var effect = 'slide';
    var options = { direction: 'right', easing: 'swing' };
    var duration = 1000;
    $(".popup").toggle(effect, options, duration);
    var effectFade = 'fade';
    var durationFade = 1000;
    $(".toggler").toggle(effectFade, { queue: false }, durationFade);
};

function UnToggleSendForm() {

    var effect = 'slide';
    var options = { direction: 'right', easing: 'swing' };
    var duration = 1000;
    $(".popup").toggle(effect, options, duration);
    var effectFade = 'fade';
    var durationFade = 1000;
    $(".toggler").toggle(effectFade, { queue: false }, durationFade);
};
```

jQuery API Doc:

> queue (default: true) 
>   Type: Boolean or String 
>   A Boolean indicating
>   whether to place the animation in the effects queue. If false, the
>   animation will begin immediately. As of jQuery 1.7, the queue option
>   can also accept a string, in which case the animation is added to the
>   queue represented by that string. When a custom queue name is used the
>   animation does not automatically start; you must call
>   .dequeue("queuename") to start it.

Comment: didn't help. what may have an influence on div ? i guess my code is correct because have another simplest example and it works with background. So the problem what (style possibly) can break background color here.

Comment: sry, you have to set this option to the last toggle in each function, not to the first one.

Comment: i guess this is not my case. because i have an animation. all controls from inner's div (popup) are slides from right-side. My problem is that background of div is transparent. Even borders not shown while moving. So i guess its not a juery problem.